# Development environment does not see my phone

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, sony, sony-xperia

I\'m trying to debug the application via usb on my phone, but the development environment does not see my phone (Chperia Z compact e5823). The driver was updated, the developer mode was enabled, USB debugging is enabled. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problems:

- Android SDK not setup or incorrectly setup
- adb not setup or incorrectly setup

Also there are some "packages" you need to (should) install inside the android sdk manager. The Google USB Drivers, for example, is one of them.